# Changing storyboard simulated metrics is affecting size on device

Tags: ios, autolayout

Is this a bug or is something else wrong? I´m using Xcode 6.3.2

If I change the simulated metrics size to iPhone 4.7-inch and run the app on a 4-inch the scrollview width is 375, not 320 as expected.

If I then change simulated metrics size to iPhone 4-inch and run it, the scrollview with is 320.

In the storyboard everything seems to be resizing just fine!

[image: Contraints]

[image: 4-inch]

[image: 4.7-inch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue you're having correctly, you're wondering why the scrollwidth is 375 on a 4.7 inch device, when you've changed the simulated metrics to a 4 inch phone (320 width).

Answer: The simulated metrics have nothing to do with influencing the width of on a device. You should build you application in the default "inferred" simulated metric and build the view in wAny hAny.

If you want to see how the device will look on a device, you can use the assistant editor and preview :

[image: assistant editor]

Preview:

[image: preview]

Sizes:

[image: Screen sizes]

Comment: No, the width of the scrollview becomes 320 on any device if 4.0-inch device is chosen in simulated metrics! The simulated metrics ARE influencing the size on the device strange enough....

Comment: You are right, I found the problem. 

The size of the scrollview was from the beginning the same size as the simulated metrics, but autolayout changes the size AFTER viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear. 

I was setting the contentsize to be self.contentScrollView.frame.size.width * viewCount (paging scrollview).